# Primitive quintuples of distinct positive integers

Tags: number-theory

Are there infinitely primitive quintuples of distinct positive integers such that each integer divides the sum of the four others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the sum of the numbers be $S$ and the numbers be $\dfrac{S}{a},\dfrac{S}{b},\dfrac{S}{c},\dfrac{S}{d},\dfrac{S}{e}$ so that $\sum \dfrac{1}{a}=1$. The tuple $(a,b,c,d,e)$ then uniquely determines the primitive quintuple by setting $S=lcm(a,b,c,d,e)$. Now the number of solutions to $\sum \dfrac{1}{a}=1$ can be bounded as follows. The smallest number must be at most 5; for each value of this, the smallest of the remaining is again bounded and so on.

Thus the number of primitive quintuples is finite.